# Only keep the escape key on touch bar keyboard

Tags: macos, touch-bar

I would like to remove all the keys on the touch bar except the escape key.

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/358975/151404

Answer (score 3):

```
System Preferences -> Keyboard ->
  Touch Bar shows: Quick Actions
  Press Fn key to: Show Control Strip
```

After that you only have `Esc` and `Configure in: Extension Preferences` buttons on the Touch Bar, while quick actions are accessible through pressing the hardware `Fn` key.

Now, the question is how to also remove that `Configure in: Extension Preferences` button as it still results in accidental key presses, but at least it only shows a preferences window, which is easy to quickly close with `Cmd+W`.

Answer (score 2):

`System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Touch Bar shows: Expanded Control Strip`

After that `Customise Control Strip...` and drag out all buttons from touch bar.

Answer (score 1):

After killing the Touch Bar server application it worked like a charm. I follow what described in this topic : https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/382627/363577