# Fully disable MacBook Pro's Touch Bar

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

I constantly keep touching my MacBook Pro's Touch Bar by accident. I have larger hands and my fingers accidentally press buttons on the Touch Bar without me noticing all the time.

I like the Touch Bar and I'd like to use it, but I can't seem to find anywhere that will allow me to enable a *lock screen* type feature on the Touch Bar.

I'd really like to disable input unless explicitly enabled. How do I do that?

Answer (score 25):

**Native solution (no installs required):**

You can tinker with the Keyboard Settings to get something close to your desired behavior. Here's one idea:

Set "Touch Bar shows" to "Expanded Control Strip" and remove all buttons on the Control Strip using "Customize Touch Bar...". Then set "Press Fn key to" to "Show App Controls".

Now your Touch Bar will be empty unless you press <kbd>fn</kbd> to show the App Controls.

—

I also outline some ways to use Better Touch Tool to temporarily disable the Touch Bar in my [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378596/151404) on a related question.

Comment: On my MacBook Pro 2019, running macOS 12.6.8, I can set "Touch Bar shows" to "Quick Actions" and uncheck "Show Control Strip". I see nothing on the touch bar and didn't have to fool with customizing the touch bar.

Don't have to install BarNone or any other tool either. Works great in my case.

Answer (score 11):

For my 2019 16" MBP I ended up with this:

```
$fn = 20;

module RoundRect(w, d, h2, r, scale=1) {
  h = h2/2;
  linear_extrude(height=2*h, scale=scale)
  translate([-w/2+r, -d/2+r, 0])
  minkowski() {
    circle(r=r);
    square([w-2*r, d-2*r]);
  }
}
//RoundRect(10, 11, 1, 2);

module Cover() {
  w = 242;
  d = 11;
  h = 1;
  h1 = 0.5;
  xside = 15;
  holeDist = 5;
  solid = xside + 11 * holeDist;
  holeW = (w - solid)/12;
  x0 = -w/2 + xside/2 + holeW/2;
  xDist = holeW + holeDist;

  mirror([0, 0, 1])
  difference() {
    union() {
      RoundRect(w+2, d+2, h, 3);
      translate([0, 0, h]) RoundRect(w+2, d+2, h1, 3, [w/(w+1), d/(d+1)]);
    }
    translate([0, 0, -1]) RoundRect(w, d, h+1, 2);
    for (x = [0:11]) translate([x0+x*xDist, 0, 0]) RoundRect(holeW, d-6, h+1, 1);
  }
}

Cover();
```

This is a cover for the touch bar you can create with OpenSCAD.

[image]

It fits snugly (at least for the over-extrusion my DIY Prusa creates). For now this thingy converts that nonsense-bar into something more like a "keyboard". You can rest your fingers on the strip and to actually press a key you need some explicit force inside the holes. And if eventually in some future I might have the need for that touch bar I can pull the cover off and store it aside.

For another MBP (elder one or different size) you need to adapt the sizes. The ones I used were measured with a caliper.

Comment: P.S. I found an (expensive) alternative way: sell the MBP and get the new one where they came to senses and restored a real keyboard. Well, giving them extra money for that does not really make me feel happier, though.

Comment: "giving them extra money" - or you can go linux or windows :) Get more bang for buck

Answer (score 7):

My Touch Bar was going cuckoo, and it would randomly press the buttons in it for no reason. Restarting the computer or killing the process did not solve the problem. While changing the Touch Bar options to "Expanded Control Strip" gave me the option to empty it, the 'esc' button was still there, randomly being pressed and driving me insane.

The way I solved the issue was less gentle than some of the options suggested here (but I didn't want to download a new app to deal with the touch bar):

1. Find the touch app process in the "Activity Monitor", in my case named "Control Strip".
2. Find its PID number (e.g. pidnum).
3. Open the terminal and type `kill -STOP pidnum`. This will suspend the touch bar, which will now become unresponsive. Alternatively, one can also use: `killall -STOP "ControlStrip"`
4. Since my 'esc' button is in the damn touch bar, I also changed my keyboard settings to use my 'caps lock' as 'esc' button. That is, **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Modifier Keys**, and change accordingly.

If you need to turn the touch bar on again, you can always type `kill -CONT pidnum`.

One of the problems (potentially many) of my solution is that whenever you restart your computer, the touch bar will be enabled again. So you will need to `kill -STOP` the process again. You can always run a little script at the login that finds the PID number and runs the `kill -STOP` command. I haven't tried doing so, but it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Super use of signals! Great solution

Comment: Great answer. Thankfully my touch doesn't include the ESC key so I can continue to use that.

Comment: Does it work for you on macOS Monterey? I tried all you said but looks like Apple decided to ignore everything I execute (it doesn't even kill the process with low level commands like `kill`!!). Doing it from ActivityMonitor will restart the process immediately...

Comment: This is a great idea and answer, but when I try it on my 2019 MBP, the keypresses seems to buffer, and when I `-CONT` the process, the buffered keystroke(s) fire anyway. :(

Comment: Seems to work as desired if I wait for the "screensaver" of the touchbar to kick in (which makes all the buttons go away until activity is detected) before `-STOP`ping the process.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! Exactly the same issue, the barnone app didn't fully solve it.

Answer (score 6):

Fully disabling it seems not to be possible, as some vital functions like the Escape key require it.

What I found others doing was to put scotch tape over the touch bar. This makes it less sensitive up to completely unresponsive.

If you configure the touch bar to just show the control or function keys (whichever you prefer), and put some holes in the scotch tape before applying it, you can still press the keys and not do it accidentally.

I also suggest to log a complaint with Apple that the touch bar is too sensitive and gets pressed accidentally, so their engineers get a reason to improve it in future models, so no scotch tape is needed.

Comment: This is an awful kludge, but I might have to resort to this. I truly hate the Touch Bar on my new MacBook, enough so that I am thinking of ending my 30+ love affair with all things Apple in favor of Linux machinery.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yeah, too silly that thing? Who dares to let this run free for any Apple customer? I had been skipping that Esc-disater and thought it would be ok now. It isn't. Anyhow, I paid more than 3k and my old MBP really had its best days. The printed cover makes it acceptable. Somehow. At least it doesn't dang all times any more.

Comment: apple's user experience gets worse every day. now we are down to scotch taping their garbage products

Comment: the very latest macbooks have a physical Esc key... must be from too many complaints about having only a virtual one... i just bought a "refurb" macbook pro but i knew instantly it wasn't a refurb when i opened it.. Apple will call new macbooks refurbs when clearing out defunct models at a lower price... i predicted the return of the physical Esc key because of my own frustration at accidental touches and new macbooks selling at refurb prices... additionally: i use Karabiner to disable the touch bar Esc button and map the tilde/backtick key to Esc

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I do not have a touchbar Mac to test, but it seems like [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai) is able to do what you want:

[image]

Comment: With BetterTouchTool, you can also put a bunch of non-interactive widgets in there. I added a clock & calendar, mostly inspired by the post here: https://vas3k.com/blog/touchbar/ Super useful.

Comment: A limitation is that this does nothing to disable the touch bar on the Mac's lock / login screen. I added an answer to at least disable those keys via Karabiner-Elements, even though they're still visible.

Comment: I bought BetterTouchTool specifically because of that infuriating touch bar. It has a lot of nice features, but ultimately had to stop using it because the system was less stable while it was running. Sometimes sticking with the base OS is best if you have work to do.

Answer (score 2):

As part of disabling the Touch Bar as much as possible on the Mac, here is how to prevent the default Touch Bar buttons on your lock screen / login screen from being able to do anything, if you accidentally press them.

My example is the 2019 16-inch MacBook Pro (physical <kbd>Esc</kbd> key) so it has 8 default irremovable buttons:

[image]

1. Install [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/). Make sure your Touch Bar device is ticked under `Devices` tab for what it can modify.
2. In Simple modifications tab, this is what it looks like to disable all the above 8 keys:
   [image]

- The last four buttons are listed under `Media controls` list by default.
- The first four buttons need to be added manually via key detection by Karabiner-EventViewer (`Karabiner-Elements` menu bar > `EventViewer`). For each button, press it in EventViewer then add it to Karabiner-Elements as shown by the arrow.
  [image]
- Remap each key to `VK_none` to make them do nothing.

I have not found a way to disable the Touch Bar at the driver level (i.e. the kext files), based on a cursory look.

Answer (score 1):

After checking this post and not finding a right and free option, I found **[Bar None](http://shauninman.com/assets/downloads/barnone.zip)** It’s also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/shauninman/shauninman.com/blob/main/assets/downloads/barnone.zip).

**It allows you to lock the Touch Bar unless you press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.** Now I have F controls by default, but they do not work, unless I press <kbd>Fn</kbd> and then I get the *Control Strip*.

Comment: Link is dead :/

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the comment @mix3d! I have contacted the author and he just restored it, I will edit my answer with the new link

Comment: Awesome, because accidental touches of this @$%* touchbar are a BEAR.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to completely remove everything from the touchbar by switching it to Expanded Control Stip mode in Keyboart Settings and then using "Customise Control Strip ..." in the same settings dialog to remove all the buttons from it.

Well, it's not physically disabling the device, but there's nothing in it to accidentally touch.

The volume keys can be re-mapped to something like Option <> (with Karabiner Elements for example)

Works on Big Sur 11.2.1