# Move Escape key on Touch Bar

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

I keep accidentally hitting the Escape key when I'm typing. I'd like to move to more towards the center of the Touch Bar, or require a double-click to activate it. Is this possible?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/358975/151404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no native way to move (or adjust the sensitivity of) the escape key on the Touch Bar.

Some potential solutions:

1. Upgrade to a new MacBook with a physical ESC key
2. Use [Better Touch Tool](https://folivora.ai/) to temporarily hide your entire Touch Bar (solutions below)
3. Use an external keyboard

### Using BTT to hide the Touchbar

This solution was posed in a [BTT GitHub issue](https://github.com/folivoraAI/BetterTouchTool/issues/204#issuecomment-383396353):

> 1. Uncheck "Show MacOS Control Strip" and "Show Escape Button" in general touchbar settings.
> 2. Create a button with no action and put a bunch of blank spaces in the name and make the button black (this moves the button you'll
>      create in the following step over to the right so your pinky won't hit it).
> 3. Create a "Toggle BTT Touchbar" button with "Toggle BetterTouchTool Touchbar" as its action. This let's you get the standard touchbar back if/when you need it.

This solution is from the [Apple discussion board](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7762774):

> Click "TouchBar"  Click "General Touch Bar Settings"  Check "Enable
>   Touch Bar Support"    Uncheck "Show macOS Control Strip"  Check Show
>   "BTT icon in Control Strip"   All Other items are unchecked   Click
>   Close     14  ￼   Click "+ TouchBar Button"   Give the button a Name...I
>   chose "Unhide the Touch Bar with Satan Spawn ESC key" For "Predefined
>   Action:" choose "Toggle BTT Touch Bar” ￼    Click "Advanced
>   Configuration" for the button and choose where you want it to
>   appear...I chose the right side for "Item Placement..."   ￼   Now my
>   Touch Bar looks like this:   ￼   With nothing else on the Touch Bar:
>   ￼
>     This Touch Bar persists across all apps. If I tap the button, the
>   regular Touch Bar returns

**NOTE**: You may also need to hide the BTT icon in settings, as it will replace the ESC key when the Touch Bar is empty.

Comment: You say there’s no way to change it, but you reference BTT to customize it, which implies there **is** a way to change it. How would you utilize BTT to achieve the OP’s goal?

Comment: @Allan By “native” I mean that there’s no way to do it without 3rd party software - does that make sense? Regarding specific implementation of BTT for this issue, I agree that I left it vague - this is both bc I don’t have direct experience with the tool and from what I’ve read there are a few different solutions (one of which was included in the linked thread, which I’ve now highlighted as part of the BTT bullet).

Comment: What I’m getting at, is I’m trying to follow your links, but none lead to a solution.  If there is something on the BTT site, it should be summarized here and linked to for reference.  The ultimate goal is to provide an ***answer to the question*** and that’s what bings the upvotes.

Comment: @Allan makes sense. I did some more research and updated the answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Thank you for this! It was also a great way to start to understand how BTT works, which I had been having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. You can use **[Bar None](http://shauninman.com/assets/downloads/barnone.zip)** and then you will need to press the `fn` key in order to enable the Touch Bar, thus the `Esc` button too.  It can also be downloaded via [GitHub](https://github.com/shauninman/shauninman.com/blob/main/assets/downloads/barnone.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can stick something there (thin and soft so it won't scratch the screen). Then dedicate a physical key (e.g. CapsLock or backtick[1](https://adamfeuer.com/blog/2017/09/18/change-backtick-to-escape-key-for-macbook-pro-with-touchbar/)) to ESC.

My test shows two layers of tissue can make it completely insensitive.

Comment: I’ve seen other people use tape as well! Good point about the ability to map another key to ESC.

Comment: electrical tape works great