# Is there a way to adjust the touch sensitivity of the touch bar on my M1 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar, apple-silicon

I've got a MacBook Pro M1 and the touch bar is too sensitive if my finger even comes close to it, it acts like I pressed it.  This causes me to change pages and do all kinds of stuff I don't want to do.  Drives me bonkers.  Never want a touch bar again....

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/358975/151404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now there isn't an option like that on the new macbook m1 . But I think this solution might help you from touching touchbar unintentionally .

Here's one idea:

Set "Touch Bar shows" to "Expanded Control Strip" and remove all buttons on the Control Strip using "Customize Touch Bar...". Then set "Press Fn key to" to "Show App Controls".

Now your Touch Bar will be empty unless you press fn to show the App Controls.

Comment: I did what you said, except for I need to change it to Touch Bar show "Quick Actions", FN Do Nothing, Press and Hold FN Show App Controls.  If you want to update you answer to reflect this I'll mark you as a good answer.  Thanks

Comment: Did the same. Thanks for the tips, this is a lifesaver!