# Esc button from touchbar has disappeared

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, touch-bar

After a clean reinstall of OSX Catalina 10.15.2 on a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018), Esc button from the touchbar has disappeared.

I don't have any 3rd party tool or app installed.

Any idea on how to bring it back ?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

After killing Touch Bar server application it will come back. Just paste the following to terminal and enter your password when asked:

```
sudo pkill TouchBarServer
```

Comment: Works great! Do you know why only the esc button disappears?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: this answer has saved the life of so many tmux sessions! thank you

Comment: Of all the things to mess with, Apple, why the escape key…

Comment: Did not work for me on the latest available Public Beta 4 of Monterey.

Comment: @talha06 We have chance to try it on  Big Sur but not on Monterey. I don't know if it is beta or something changed. But Apple is preparing to leave the touch bar behind on their new MacBooks so maybe it is related to that too, I don't know, we'll see.

Answer (score 3):

This option got it back on the Fn key, before following @mehyaa's suggestion.

[image: Mac > Keyboard > Keyboard > Press Fn key to]