# There is no process "Touch Bar Agent"

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, catalina, touch-bar

My MBP 15" 2018's touch bar died few days back.

I read a lot of people suggesting to kill process "Touch Bar Agent". But, I don't find process "Touch Bar Agent" in the activity monitor, nor via grep in terminal.

Interestingly, my another MBP which has a working touch bar does not show process "Touch Bar Agent" as well.

I am running "macOS Catalina 10.15.6". Did apple change the process name in latest updates?

Edit:
There are numerous post here which suggest to kill that process, suggesting the process used to exist in older releases. Example: [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389362/macbook-touchbar-pressing-some-buttons-on-its-own/389363#389363)

Comment: Try looking for it in Terminal with the command `ps -A | grep -i "touch bar"`  That will list all the processes that contain the words "touch bar" regardless of case.

Comment: I checked that already, its not there..

Comment: Could this be why your Touch Bar is no longer working?  Did you reboot your Mac?

Comment: Yes, I tried mostly all solutions I found on internet. My other MBP, which has working touch bar, does not has this process..

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched for "TouchBarServer" ? Maybe this is the process you are looking for ?
[image: Activity monitor]

Comment: No, I was looking for process “Touch Bar Agent”.. Numerous posts here suggest to kill that process.. but it seems the process is removed/renamed in latest releases

Comment: There are numerous post here which suggest to kill that process, suggesting the process used to exist in older releases. Example: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389362/macbook-touchbar-pressing-some-buttons-on-its-own/389363#389363

Comment: @gyan When I kill the process on my screenshot, the touch bar stops working. Have you tried search this process to kill it?

Answer (score -1):

924 ttys000    0:00.00 grep -i touch bar

I got this when typed ps -A | grep -i "touch bar"

Though my touchbar is totally blank. doesnt respond to any touches though the Touch Id is working fine and everytime.